# Apply notch filter on image spectrum (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, filter, dft, spectrum

How can I apply a notch filter on an image spectrum using OpenCV 2.4 and C++? I want to calculate the DFT of an image, suppress certain frequencies and calculate inverse dft. Can anyone show me some sample code how to apply a notch filter in frequecy domain?

EDIT:

Here is what I tried, but the quadrants of the frequency spectrum are not in order so the origin of the spectrum is not the center of the image. That makes is difficult for me to identify the frequencies to suppress. When swapping quadrants so that the origin is the center, inverse DFT shows wrong results. Can anyone show me how to do inverse dft with swapped quadrants?

I don't understand the number of columns in the frequency images filter1 and filter2 (see code). If I use filter1.cols as u in the for loop, I don't access the right border of the images. Filter1 and filter2 seem to have approx. 5000 columns but the source image has a resolution of 1280x1024 (grayscale). Any thoughts on that?

Any further comments about my code?

```
    Mat img;
img=imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

int M = getOptimalDFTSize( img.rows );
int N = getOptimalDFTSize( img.cols );
Mat padded;
copyMakeBorder(img, padded, 0, M - img.rows, 0, N - img.cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));

Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(padded), Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F)};
Mat complexImg;
merge(planes, 2, complexImg);

dft(complexImg, complexImg,cv::DFT_SCALE|cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);

   split(complexImg, planes);

Mat filter1;
planes[0].copyTo(filter1);
Mat filter2;
planes[1].copyTo(filter2);

for( int i = 0; i < filter1.rows; ++i)
{
    for(int u=7;u<15;++u)
    {
        filter1.at<uchar>(i,u)=0;
        filter2.at<uchar>(i,u)=0;
    }


Mat inverse[] = {filter1,filter2};
Mat filterspec;
merge(inverse, 2, filterspec);

cv::Mat inverseTransform;
cv::dft(filterspec, inverseTransform,cv::DFT_INVERSE|cv::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);

cv::Mat finalImage;
inverseTransform.convertTo(finalImage, CV_8U);
```

Comment: I used dft to calculate the spectrum and tried to use mulSpectrums to multiply the spectrum of the image with a matrix filled with ones except for one row which was filled with zeros. How can I calculate the dft of an image and set one row of the spectrum to zero and do inverse dft afterwards? If possible, I want to use the form of the spectrum, where the origin is the center (after switching quadrants), so its easier to find out which row must be zero.

Comment: This is a bad idea - see [this post](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-filter-by-zeroing-out-fft-bins) on DSP.SE (which is also probably a more appropriate site for your question)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to try that anyway...

Comment: You need to be aware that zeroing bins in the frequency domain produces severe artefacts in the spatial domain - if you're going to do this you need to apply a window function in the frequency domain so that you get a smooth transition - this will help to reduce these artefacts.

Comment: Can you post some sample code how to modify the frequency components and how to calculate inverse dft afterwards?

Comment: It's really very simple - you should try to do it yourself and then post a question on SO if you get stuck (be sure to include any code that you've written so far).

Comment: I added some code. Main problems: I can't do inverse dft with swapped quadrants and I am not sure if I access the frequency components correctly.